# Writing a rspec test for a conditional if statement returns no example found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am fairly new to RSPEC and trying to write a test for a functionality below:

```
private

def state_email
    if CurrentXPX.is?(:Ohio)
      :oh_update_reminder
    elsif CurrentXPX.is?(:North_Carolina)
      :nc_update_reminder
    else CurrentXPX.is?(:Missouri)
      :mo_update_reminder
    end
end
```

The `CurrentXPX.is? function which return state abbreviations looks like this:

```
module CurrentXPX
 class << self
    def is?(state)
      s = State::Abbreviations.const_get state
      return state_abbreviation == s
    end
```

The ':oh_update_reminder' function returns this statement:

```
class AccountUpdateReminder < ActionMailer::Base
     def oh_update_reminder(email)
        mail(to: email, subject: AccountUpdateReminder.subject)
     end

     def nc_update_reminder(email)
        mail(to: email, subject: AccountUpdateReminder.subject)
     end

     def mo_update_reminder(email)
        mail(to: email, subject: AccountUpdateReminder.subject)
     end
end
```

Finally, I have wrote down a test like this:

```
 describe 'state_email' do
    
    context 'ohio state email' do
      it 'send ohio update reminder' do
        if (CurrentXPX.is?("Ohio"))
          let(:oh_update_reminder){ mail(to: email, subject: AccountUpdateReminder.subject)}
          expect(:oh_update_reminder).to be_truthy
        end
      end
    end

    context 'North Carolina state email' do
      it 'send north carolina update reminder' do
        if (CurrentXPX.is?("North_Carolina"))
          let(:nc_update_reminder){ mail(to: email, subject: AccountUpdateReminder.subject)}
          expect(:nc_update_reminder).to be_truthy
        end
      end
    end

    context 'Missouri state email' do
      it 'send Missouri update reminder' do
        if (CurrentXPX.is?("Missouri"))
          let(:mo_update_reminder){ mail(to: email, subject: AccountUpdateReminder.subject)}
          expect(:mo_update_reminder).to be_truthy
        end
      end
    end

  end
```

When running the rspec test I got the:

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- blah blah blah
No examples found.

Top 0 slowest examples (0 seconds, 0.0% of total time):

Finished in 0.00003 seconds (files took 0.6038 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures, 1 error occurred outside of examples
```

I am highly suspect that my Rspec test is not correct, but it might also be more. I appreciate any help/hint I can get.

Comment: What's `CurrentXPX`? In the code you're using symbols, in the specs you're gating the `expect`s with strings.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing a `subject` declaration and calling it within the examples, so the rspec is not actually testing anything.

Are you trying to test the method `#state_email`? In which case you would need

```rb
describe '#state_email' do
  subject(:state_email) { described_class.new.state_email }
     
  it "is [your criteria here]" do
    expect(state_email).to be_present # your test here
  end
end
```

or are you trying to test the methods in `AccountUpdateReminder`?

```rb
RSpec.describe AccountUpdateReminder do
  describe "#oh_update_reminder" do
    let(:email) { "test@test.com" }
    subject(:oh_update_reminder) { described_class.new.oh_update_reminder(email) }

    it "mails" do
      expect(described_class).to receive(:mail).with(to: email)
      oh_update_reminder
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The first solution is what I am trying to implement. What I forgot was to mention that the state_email method is actually private method. When I ran a test I gave me a 'NoMethodError' due to state_email being a private method. I will update that on the code as well.

Comment: Okay, you can't really test private methods directly. You need to test the public methods in the class that use them to ensure the total functionality in the public method is completed, including whatever the private method is doing.